# How to set default time zone in javascript date object

Tags: javascript, timestamp-with-timezone

How to set default timezone in date object.

```
const date=new Date(val).getTime().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "Asia/Dubai" }),
```

Comment: `Date` object always sets the local timezone (computer timezone) I suppose. why do you need to do that?
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone) should answer your question.

Comment: I need to set particular timezone and also convert that time into milliseconds

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript) should help.